# To pass a normal function into the jquery plugin and then call that function inside the plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-callback, jquery-1.9

Can I pass a normal js function into the jquery plugin and then call that function inside the plugin?

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

    responsive: function(options,callbacks) {

    var defaults = {
                setup:                      {},
                windowTargetWidth:          1903,
                beforeRespond:              function() {},
                onRespond:                  function() {},
                onElse:                     function() {}
            };

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $this = this;

            return this.ready(function(e){

                var window_loaded_width = $(window).width();

                $(window).resize(function() {

                    options.beforeRespond(ratio);

                    // Make the website responsive
                    if(window_loaded_width < o.windowTargetWidth )
                    {
                        // call the function
                        setup.func;

                        //options.onRespond(ratio);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var window_resized_width = $(window).width();
                        var ratio =  window_resized_width/window_loaded_width; 

                        options.onElse(ratio);
                    }

                });


            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);


$(window).responsive({
    setup: {
        func: responsive_element(ratio)
    },

    beforeRespond: function(ratio){

        // something happens...

    },

    onRespond: function(ratio){

        responsive_element(ratio);
    },
    onElse: function(ratio){

        responsive_element(ratio);
    }
});

function responsive_element(ratio){
    $("#container").css({
        "width": 5400 * ratio
    });
}
```

Of course, I get an error -

> ratio is not defined

for this line,

```
func: responsive_element(ratio)
```

Maybe I do it wrong?

The reason I want to pass the function in and call it within the plugin is that it is repetitive to have `responsive_element(ratio)` twice or more when I attach this plugin to the object `$(window).responsive({...})`

Ideally I just have to put in the function **once** in the `setup` or somewhere - is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

in  your case to call a function within your plugin use
o.beforeRespond.call(this)